# Drop Down Menu For Nopcommerece 3.60v

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

In TopMenu.cshtml (Nopcommerce v3.60) I added the code given below for a dropdown menu and it worked fine in v3.50. Now I've upgraded to v3.60 and this code does not show the drop down menu, only the menu heading.

Please guide me as to what's the solution.

```
 <li id="Gen">
            <a href="">Gen</a>
            <ul id="GenSubMenu" class="dropdown-ul">
                <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Topic", new { SeName = Html.GetTopicSeName("HondaCivic") })">@T("Honda Civic")</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Topic", new { SeName = Html.GetTopicSeName("HondaCity") })">@T("Honda City")</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Topic", new { SeName = Html.GetTopicSeName("ToyotaCorolla") })">@T("Toyota Corolla")</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    <style type="text/css">
        .top-menu ul.dropdown-ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background: #404040;
            margin-left: -8px;
        }

        .top-menu ul.dropdown-ul.active {
            display: block;
        }

        .top-menu ul.dropdown-ul li {
            float: none;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Gen').live('mouseenter', function () {
            $('#GenSubmenu').addClass('active');
        });
        $('#Gen').live('mouseleave', function () {
            $('#GenUsSubmenu').removeClass('active');
        });
    </script>
```